# Azure Cache Service - Crazy High Miss %

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

I've recently signed up for the Azure caching service (Oct. 2013). It is configured correctly and I am able to put and get items from the cache.

My dashboard / monitor view, however, displays a ridiculously high "Miss %" (anywhere from 75% - 80%). If I understand correctly, this means that 3 out of 4 times I ask for something from the cache, it isn't there.

This strikes me as pretty darn high and I'm wondering if a) I'm doing it wrong or b) I'm not understanding the metric / process correctly.

The main use of the cache in my app is for lookup lists and user state management (an IPrincipal with some custom properties).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add more details around this, such as cache expiry setting (on the cache's Configure tab), along with code snippets for how you're storing and retrieving your state management?

Comment: I'm also seeing a very high miss percentage (72.65%).  Since implementing the new azure caching distributed service, my sites seem to be up to 10x slower.  It's the cache service as a site I host that does not use cache runs extremely fast.  Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see other counters like Evicted Objects, Expired Objects increasing too ? The reasons that you would see Cache Miss% going high is because that the key was not found which can be because either the key expired or was evicted. If you see high eviction rate then you should reconsider reassessing the capacity for your cache, refer [Capacity Planning for Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386139.aspx).

Can you share any client side error too ?